# Using an SQL INNER JOIN with OleDbDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, sql, join, oledbdatareader

I am using the **OleDbDataReader** to access an Access Database with 3 tables. The database contains the main ***"Membership"*** table with a column ID, and a ***"Payment"*** and ***"Boat"*** table both using the ID as a foreign key called PID and BID respectively.

The following SQL query runs correctly and returns the correct values from  the Membership and Payment tables.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Membership 
INNER JOIN Payment ON Membership.ID = Payment.PID;
```

Whereas the following SQL query generates an error when trying to access all 3 tables:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Membership 
INNER JOIN Payment ON Membership.ID = Payment.PID 
INNER JOIN Boat ON Membership.ID = Boat.BID;
```

**Error:** *Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Membership.ID = Payment.PID INNER JOIN Boat ON Membership.ID = Boat.BI'.*

Due to the error I am starting to wonder whether the OleDbDataReader is capable of executing two INNER JOINs as it asks for a missing operator, however I have tried all the usual ones and cannot seem to get the query to run correctly. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access requires additional parentheses for multiple joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM (Membership INNER JOIN
      Payment
      ON Membership.ID = Payment.PID
     ) INNER JOIN
     Boat
     ON Membership.ID = Boat.BID;
```

You should also explicitly list the columns that you want to avoid duplicate column names.

Comment: This worked thanks, the only reason I don't list the columns is because I have around 20 columns and it's a small enough amount to avoid duplicates while also a large amount to list out. Thanks :)